# node.js TSOA and socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io, tsoa

I have a node.js and TSOA project
I am wondering if anyone has tried to inject a socket.io reference into
all of the routes?

Here is my setup:

```
import * as express from 'express';
import * as cors from 'cors';
import * as bodyparser from '../vender/body-parser';
import * as socketio from 'socket.io';

import { requestLoggerMiddleware } from './request.logger.middleware';


import { RegisterRoutes } from './routes/routes';
import * as swaggerUi from 'swagger-ui-express';

const app = express();
app.use(
  cors({
    origin: ['http://localhost:4200', '*'],
    credentials: true,
  })
);

app.use(bodyparser.json());
app.use(requestLoggerMiddleware);
RegisterRoutes(app);  // <- These are auto generated don't touch!!!

let http = require('http').Server(app);
let io = require('socket.io')(http);
io.on('connection', function (socket: any) {
  console.log('a user connected');
  socket.on("message", function(message: any) {
    console.log(message);
    socket.emit('message', 'testtest');
  });
});
```

It would be amazing if i could get access to the `io` object in all of the routes without having to re-define it every route. Any idea if this is possible?

Thanks all!

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: I did, and that was basically to move this into its own file that all of my constructors were derived from, Since that time I moved to Nest.js, Nx, and Angular, Since then I have found all of the issues like these go away.

Answer (score 0):

You could store it in the app object in index.js like this

```
app.set('socketio', io);
```

And then access it through the request object from each route

```
const io = request.app.get('socketio')
```